# Outlook 2010 (32-bit) Insert File dialog search feature does not work

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, search

While trying to attach files to a new email using the Insert File dialog (in Microsoft Outlook 2010), the dialog's search textbox does not seem to work.

It simply fails to display any search results; no error message is displayed.

The exact same query works almost instantly using Explorer's in-built search feature, however.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User, Gordon. Can you be more specific about what you are doing and how? Are you getting an error message? These additional details will help us answer your question.

Comment: See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts. Then you'll be able to edit your question without needing to go through peer review.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming Windows 7):

By default that dialog opens to Libraries -> Documents, so if your file isn't somewhere within that folder (or it's sub-folders) it's not going to find it.

When you open Explorer, by default it points at "Libraries", so it has a wider search scope (by default).